# Iphone: UITableView how to detect that row is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView`, and I press the row, but do not release finger, so `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called yet, right?

1. How to detect on which row i clicked? in which method?
2. How to detect that I clicked on table view? Is there any method like `rowIsPressed`? or `onTableViewTouchDown`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options at least:

1) You can subclass UITableViewCell and than use the touchhandling you know from a default uiview. (Like `touchesBegan:` etc.) / OR add a custom uiview as contentView of the tablecell.

2) Add a gesturerecognizer to each tablecell.

To find out in which row you are, you could give every row a tag (which than refers to the row) in `cellForRow:atIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to detect the selected state before lifting the finger... I guess you should override the UITableView class and add a UIGestureRecognizer to it.
And about your second question, I think you are talking about this table view delegate method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But there is also another method that will give you the current selected row. This is it (directly from the table view class):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Hope to have helped!